# Cannot pull image from minikube docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

When I try to run a container in the cluster, I get a message "`deployment test created`" but when I look at the dashboard I can see that its in an error state (`Failed to pull image...`, it was not able to pull the image from the local minikube docker env due to authorization issues

My steps were:

1. Start minikube using hyperv and setting the `--insecure-registry` switch to 10.0.0.0/8, also tried 0.0.0.0/0 - Kubernetes version 1.9.0 also tried 1.8.0
2. Set the `docker env` to the minikube docker via `minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression`
3. build docker image - image builds and exists in minikube local docker
4. `kubectl run test --image test-service --port 1101`

This is the result:

[image: Failed Deployment]

What am I missing?

Comment: Additionally - I have now also tried this with the new built in local kubenetes solution as provided by Docker - same result...I documented the issue here

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1724

Comment: Is it similar to https://github.com/openfaas/faas-netes/issues/135? I suppose there is noo typo as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/48818237/6309?

Comment: @VonC Whilst this was not exactly what my issue was, it did point me in the right direction - I realized it was not an auth issue, but that it was always wanting to pull from an external repo.

The fix for me was to use the imagePullPolicy of IfNotPresent

But it was your link that led me down that path, so whack in an answer and the 100 points are yours :-)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it was night time on my side ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, `openfaas/faas-netes` issue 135 illustrates a similar issue, and mention as a possible solution:

> `imagePullPolicy` if not mentioned should have defaulted to `Never` instead of `Always`.

The [OP Tim Jarvis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10387/tim-jarvis) realized then:

> I realized it was not an auth issue, but that it was always wanting to pull from an external repo.
>   The fix for me was to use the `imagePullPolicy` of `IfNotPresent`.

Answer (score 1):

This also happened with me, it is important to check the policy to send retrieve your image, there are some ways as described in some forums, you can start your minikube by setting a registry of your preference as below, being a path.

```
$ minikube start --cpus 2 --disk-size 50g --memory 5000 --insecure-registry your.registry.com:5000
```

another way is at the beginning of your minikube to present the environment variables through the docker-env, as follows and generate build of your image after the command.

```
$ eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

another alternative is to import the image to existing through the docker load.

Answer (score 1):

Set the following property within the container definition:

```
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Example:

```
  ...
  containers:
    - name: podhealthexample
      image: podhealth-pod-a:latest
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps :

- `eval $(minikube docker-env)`
- `minikube start`